# Monotouch: Combine 4 images into 1 (UIImage)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage, xamarin.ios, graphic

I have 4 UIImages (A,B,C,D), each the same 500x500

How can I combine them into a grid 1000x1000 like this:

```
AB
CD
```

So that the I have a single UIImage "E"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to create a new image context with the size of the final image:

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new SizeF(1000, 1000));
```

Then, draw each image in the appropriate rectangle:

```
image.Draw(new RectangleF(0,0,image.Size.Width,image.Size.Height));
//image2.Draw...
```

You then get the image:

```
UIImage finalImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

And finally, you must end the image context:

```
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, very well constructed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't specifically know how but I do know that Apple's [PhotoScroller sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) might help? It's a pretty cool trick they have that might work for yours too. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can't use UIGrahpics.BeginImageContext() in a sub-thread, it has to be the main thread. If you want to do it in a sub-thread you have to use CGBitmapContext(), which is a little harder to deal with.